# Select Unique Rows When Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct-values

I have 3 tables as follow:

**Customer table (custNbr varchar(7) , custRef char(3),........)**

**Item table (itemNbr varchar(10), custRef char(3), itemName varchar(50),..........);**

example values

Customer

| Customer | custRef |
| --- | --- |
| "0000001" | "100" |
| "0000002" | "120" |

Item

| Item | custRef | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "item000001" | "100" | "item 1" |
| "item000001" | "120" | "item 1" |
| "item000001" | "130" | "item 1" |
| "item000002" | "100" | "item 2" |
| "item000002" | "130" | "item 2" |

I need to run a query to get the list of items for each customer, but the criteria is like this:

If the customer custref contains "100" then I need to get only the items with custRef "100"
If the customner has a custRef other than 100, (for example "120" then:

1. it the item has both custRef of "120" and "100" get only the row with same custref as customer, which is "120"
2. if the item does not have a custRef like the customer "120". then return the row with custRef "100"

So in the example above, if I want to return items for customer "0000001"
it should return

| Customer | Item | custRef | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "0000001" | "item000001" | "100" | "item 1" |
| "0000001" | "item000002" | "100" | "item 2" |

If I want to return items for customer "0000002", it should return

| Customer | Item | custRef | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "0000001" | "item000001" | "120" | "item 1" |
| "0000001" | "item000002" | "100" | "item 2" |

Is there a way to do this in one query ?  currently I am doing join where item.custRef in (customer.custRef, "100")
and then I have to iterate on the cursor and eliminate the "100" row if I find that there is another one with a custRef like the customer.

I am using sqlserver 2014

Comment: *I am using sqlserver 2018* - hint - you're not.

Comment: 2 rows of sample data are unlikely to be sufficient to solve your problem. But help others help you - post your DDL and sample data as a script that others can use as a starting point. Your schema has a strong smell of improper normalization - so perhaps improvements in that area will be a better path to long-term success.

Comment: I did not post exact schema for the tables , the tables are huge and contain a lot more fields. I am trying to focus on the fields that I need help with only.

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize the output with `row_number()`. If I've got it right

```
select top(1) with ties c.Customer, i.*
from Customer c
join Item i on c.custRef = 100 and i.custRef = 100
         or c.custRef > 100 and i.custRef in (100, c.custRef)
order by row_number() over(partition by c.Customer, i.Item order by i.custRef desc);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e6da4b445224bbf2ab84c4a2ffab97c2)

Comment: custRef is character not numeric, so c.custRef > 100 won't work.   Also if I do that,  will it remove the duplicate and return only the rows I need ?

Comment: Yes `top(1) with tie`s will return exactly one row in every partition of `row_number()`.

Comment: Use `c.custRef <> '100'`. Also, probably you'll need a slightly modified order by depending on what is the range of custref values.